# clHow to change the coordinate in kmeans cluster

Tags: r, dataframe, k-means

I plotting the cluster plot through the Kmeans cluster. I want to change the coordinate, here in image A variable is in 4th coordinate and rest variables are in 2nd and 3rd coordinates. So I want to plot A variable in 2nd coordinate and rest of variables in 1 and 4th coordinates. Besides, I want to make the plot black in colour

[image]

code which I used:

```
df <- na.omit(HLA_A)

df <- scale(df) 

km.res <- eclust(df, "kmeans", k = 6,
                 nstart = 25, graph = TRUE)

head(km.res$cluster, 15)

fviz_cluster(km.res,  ellipse.type = "norm", ellipse.level = 0.6, repel = TRUE)
```

Comment: what do you mean by they are in different coordinates? The data points are plotted according to their scores / projections on PC1 and PC2.. can you elaborate on what you would like to plot? coordinate is quite vague here

Comment: In this cluster plot, I want to bring all the variables on the right-hand side (x-axis) to the left-hand side or to better explain I want to flip the x-axis value to the left-hand side (along with all the variables) that is 5, 0, -5,-10. How can it be done?

Also, I want to make the figure in black and white for which I seek your help.

Comment: try something like below.. not that in the original plot, there are some points that are not labelling, these are the centers of the cluster. I did not plot them

Answer (score 0):

Don't have your data, but you can try something like below. Basically you get back the data.frame for plotting, and pass it to ggplot, specifying the geoms etc:

```
library(factoextra)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
set.seed(122)
df = scale(iris[,-5])
df = df[sample(nrow(df),40),]
km.res <- eclust(df, "kmeans", k = 6,nstart = 25, graph = FALSE)

plt = fviz_cluster(km.res,  ellipse.type = "norm", ellipse.level = 0.6, repel = TRUE)
print(plt)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(plt$data,aes(x=x,y=y,shape=cluster)) + 
geom_point() + scale_x_reverse() + theme_bw() + 
geom_text_repel(aes(label=name)) +
stat_ellipse(level=0.7)
```

[image]